# Expo / React Native web target - numeric keyboard for TextInput in Safari on iPad

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am using Expo 43 / React Native web and running in Safari on iPad. This is a requirement by the client. The keyboard type does not change to numeric / number-pad. Is it possible to get the keyboard to change to numberpad without creating the iOS app and submitting via the App Store?

```js
import { TextInput } from "react-native";

            <TextInput
              keyboardType="number-pad"
            />
            <TextInput
              keyboardType="numeric"
            />
```

The above results in a regular keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it turns out the answer is that the iPad does not have a numeric keypad like a Samsung tablet does. The above keyboardType works on an iPhone in Safari. The best you can get on an iPad is that it will open the regular keyboard with the symbols section already open so the numbers will be across the top.